# Kotlin: set annotated lateinit var using reflection

Tags: kotlin, reflection, annotations

Imagine that I try to build simple dependency injection lib. Its `Injector` class, when called on a specific class, should inject all properties annotated with `@Service` annotation.

For example, given this client:

```
class ClientA {
    @Service private lateinit var service1: Service1
    @Service private lateinit var service2: Service2
    private lateinit var service3: Service3
}
```

a call to `injector.inject(ClientA())` should result in `service1` and `service2` being set (but not `service3`). Let's assume that `Injector` knows how to construct these objects.

My question is how to write the code that parses class' properties, checks their annotations and sets them in Kotlin?

Since I'm on Android, I tried to go through Java reflection:

```
fun inject(client: Any) {
    val clientClass = client::class.java
    val fields = clientClass.declaredFields
    for (field in fields) {
        if (isAnnotatedForInjection(field)) {
            injectField(client, field)
        }
    }
}

private fun isAnnotatedForInjection(field: Field): Boolean {
    val fieldAnnotations = field.annotations
    for (annotation in fieldAnnotations) {
        if (annotation is Service) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The problem is that `fieldAnnotations` is empty. Converting `ClientA`'s code to Java I see the following:

```
public final class ClientA {
   private Service1 service1;
   private Service2 service2;
   private Service3 service3;

   /** @deprecated */
   // $FF: synthetic method
   @Service
   private static void service1$annotations() {
   }

   /** @deprecated */
   // $FF: synthetic method
   @Service
   private static void service2$annotations() {
   }
}
```

Looks like Kotlin compiler creates static methods to aggregate properties' annotations. With this info, I can write some ugly code to make it work using Java's reflection API, but there must be a cleaner way, right?

Comment: is it for runtime or compile-time operation?

Comment: Have you tried `@field:Service`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, it works. Thanks. Post as an answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to place the annotation on the field, you can use `@field:Service`.

Comment: Thanks. It's good enough for me right now, but isn't there a better option to inspect runtime annotations in Kotlin? Something "Kotlin-ish"?

Comment: There is Kotlin-Reflect but it's big and I haven't worked with it, so I don't know enough about it at this time. I'm sure Dagger did *something* to remove the need for using @JvmStatic in `object`s, so there might be a similar update for no longer needing `@field:`. I wonder if they just check for both...

Comment: The point here is that Kotlin generates a field _and_ accessor method(s) for each property, and by default annotations apply to the latter; `@field:` changes that.  Details [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets).  (BTW, reflection is a much-abused tool; IMO, most of the questions about it should probably be using something else instead.  Dependency injection is one of the rare things it _is_ a good fit for!)